# Не получается отправить письмо с сервера

Tags: php, email

Помогите пожалуйста найти решение моей проблемы
Пытаюсь написать аварийный скрипт
Это скрипт обработчик формы

```
 if ($res != FALSE) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["path"] = '../buhgalter/accountant_calender.pdf';
    header("Location: ../end.php");
  }
  else{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["path"] = '../buhgalter/accountant_calender.pdf';
    $_SESSION["to"] = 'pd@mail.ru';
    $_SESSION["theme"] = 'Бухгалтерское сопровождение';
    $_SESSION["name"] = $amo_data["name"];
    $_SESSION["phone"] = $amo_data["phone"];
    $_SESSION["email"] = $amo_data["email"];
    require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHP/Emergency_script.php');
    $send = $_SESSION['send'];
    if ($send != FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../end.php");
    }
    else{
        print('Ошибка отправки');
    }
  }
```

Это аварийный скрипт

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHP/Emergency_script.php');
```

Это его содержание, сессия уничтожается при переходе на страницу end.php

```
$to = $_SESSION['to']; # Для кого
$theme = $_SESSION['theme']; # Вид заказанной услуги
$name = $_SESSION["name"]; # Имя клиета
$phone = $_SESSION["phone"]; # Телефон клиента
$email = $_SESSION["email"]; # Почта клиента
$subject = "Заявка с сайта"; #Заголовок письма

$subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";
$mail = "Пришла заявка с сайта\n".
"Имя клиента: $name\n".
"Почта для связи с клиентом: $email\n".
"Телефон для связи с клиентом: $phone\n".
"Вид услуги: $theme\n".
"Перезвонить для уточнения деталей.\n";
$headers = 'From: <no-reply@alice.kz>' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: no-reply@alice.kz' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$send = mail($to, $subject, $mail, $headers);
$_SESSION['send'] = $send;
```

Письмо просто не уходит с сервера, связался с хостером, они ответили, что письмо блокируется с их стороны. Протестировал, выяснил что если не передавать переменные ($name, $email, $phone, $theme) в содержание письма, то оно отправляется.

Подскажите как можно выйти из данной ситуации?

Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Использовать SMTP и плевать что там за правила у хостинга

Comment: @Ninazu у хостинга домена свои правила на данный счет, я не имею доступа к настройке SMTP

Comment: Обертка облегчающая жизнь
https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html
Используйте внешний, например от Gmail)
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server

Comment: Но скрипт работает если я передаю данные через $_POST, а не через $_SESSION